# Como passar meu conjunto de dados de formato wide para long cm múltiplas variáveis no R

Tags: banco-de-dados, data.frame

Tenho o seguinte data frame:

```
dput(exemplo)
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
    grupo = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", NA),
    fc_pre = c(90, 98, 77, 98, 100, 92, 89),
    fc_pos = c(70, 77, 77, 70, 79, 72, 76),
    pa_pre = c(130, 140, 160, 160, 120, 120, 150),
    pa_pos = c(120, 110, 140, 150, 130, 120, 130)),
   .Names = c("id", "grupo", "fc_pre", "fc_pos", "pa_pre", "pa_pos"), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Eu coloquei ele no formato long usando o código:

```
    library(reshape2)
    longo <- melt(exemplo, id=c("id", "grupo"))
```

Meu data frame ficou no formato longo. Mas, o R colocou a fc_pre a fc_pos a pa_pre e a pa_pos no mesmo vetor.

```
    longo
    id grupo variable value
 1   1     A   fc_pre    90
 2   2     A   fc_pre    98
 3   3     A   fc_pre    77
 4   4     B   fc_pre    98
 5   5     B   fc_pre   100
 15  1     A   pa_pre   130
 16  2     A   pa_pre   140
 17  3     A   pa_pre   160
 18  4     B   pa_pre   160
 19  5     B   pa_pre   120
```

Eu gostaria que ele ficasse da seguinte maneira:

```
 # A tibble: 14 x 5
       id grupo tempo     fc     pa
    <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
  1     1     A   pre     90    130
  2     2     A   pre     98    140
  3     3     A   pre     77    160
  4     4     B   pre     98    160
  5     5     B   pre    100    120
  6     6     B   pre     92    120
  8     1     A   pos     70    120
  9     2     A   pos     77    110
 10     3     A   pos     77    140
 11     4     B   pos     70    150
 12     5     B   pos     79    130
```

Veja que agora eu tenho um vetor chamado tempo, outro chamado fc e outro chamado pa. Alguém saberia dizer como faz para reestruturar meu data frame para ficar assim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, para fazer essa tarefa é necessário combinar primordialmente as funções a `melt` e a `dcast` do pacote `reshape2` juntamente com a função `sub`.

```
require(reshape2)
longo <- melt(df, id.vars=c("id","grupo")) # Passo as variáveis do formato wide para longo
longo$tempo <- factor(with(longo, sub(".*_","",variable))) #Crio a variável tempo
longo$variavel <- factor(with(longo, sub("_.*","",variable))) #Crio a variável em questão
longo <- longo[,-3]
longo <- dcast(longo, id + grupo + tempo ~ variavel) # Volto as variáveis que ficaram no formato "wide" para longo.
```

Após isso, o dataframe ficará assim:

```
  id grupo tempo fc  pa
1  1     A   pos 70 120
2  1     A   pre 90 130
3  2     A   pos 77 110
4  2     A   pre 98 140
5  3     A   pos 77 140
6  3     A   pre 77 160
```

Repare que para esse código funcionar, é necessário que as colunas no dataframe original (df) obedecam algum padrão para que a função sub() seja capaz de separar corretamente o nome da variável, do momento que ela foi mensurada.

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme Parreira, deu certo aqui. Consegui reproduzir o exemplo. Só preciso entender algumas funções. Obrigado