# O que são dados no formato wide/long?

Tags: r, data.frame

É comum ler/ouvir comentários dizendo que os dados estão no formato *wide* ou *long*.

1. O que quer dizer que uma tabela está em formato *wide*? E *long*?
2. Quais pacotes/funções no `R` podem ser usados para transformar uma tabela *wide* em *long* e vice-e-versa?

---

Existe [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231749/), mas ela está restrita a um dos casos e apenas a sua operacionalização, sem entrar em questões conceituais.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Diferença entre *wide* e *long*

#### Wide format

No formato amplo (*wide format*), as respostas de um mesmo indivíduos estarão em uma única linha e cada resposta estará em uma coluna separada.

Por exemplo, no seguinte conjunto de dados, cada condado foi medido em quatro pontos de tempo, uma vez a cada 10 anos, a partir de 1970. A variável de resultado é *Jobs* e indica o número de empregos em cada condado. Existem três variáveis ​​preditoras: Área da Terra, Amenidade Natural (4 = não e 3 = Sim) e a proporção da população do condado naquele ano que se formou no *College*.

Como a área da terra e a presença de uma amenidade natural não mudam de década para década, esses preditores têm apenas uma variável por município. Mas tanto o nosso resultado, *Jobs*, e um preditor, *College*, têm valores diferentes em cada ano, por isso exigem uma variável diferente (coluna) para cada ano.

[image: Imgur]

#### Long format

No formato longo (*long format*), cada linha é um ponto de tempo por assunto. Portanto, cada sujeito (condado) terá dados em várias linhas. Todas as variáveis ​​que não mudam ao longo do tempo terão o mesmo valor em todas as linhas.

Você pode ver os mesmos dados dos cinco condados abaixo no formato longo. Cada condado tem quatro linhas de dados - uma para cada ano.

Todas as mesmas informações estão lá; nós apenas configuramos os dados de forma diferente.

Não precisamos mais de quatro colunas para *Jobs* ou *College*. Em vez disso, todos os quatro valores de *Jobs* para cada condado estão empilhados. Eles estão todos na coluna *Jobs*. O mesmo vale para os quatro valores do *College*.

Mas, para acompanhar qual observação ocorreu em que ano, precisamos adicionar uma variável *Year*.

Você notará que as variáveis ​​que não mudaram de ano para ano - Área da Terra e Amenidade Natural - têm o mesmo valor em cada uma das quatro linhas de cada condado. Parece estranho, mas não há problema em ter isso desse jeito e, desde que você analise os dados usando os procedimentos corretos, levará em conta que eles são redundantes.

[image: Imgur]

[Fonte](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/wide-and-long-data/)

2. Pacotes

   - **tidyr** - Funções: `gather` (formato *wide* para *long*) e `spread` (formato *long* para *wide*)
   - **reshape2** - Funções: `melt` (formato *wide* para *long*) e `dcast` (formato *long* para *wide*)
   - **base** - Função: `reshape`
3. Materiais adicionais: [link1](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/); [link2](https://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape/)

Answer (score 6):

> O que quer dizer que uma tabela está em formato wide? E long?

- Um banco de dados em formato *wide* é aquele no qual as variáveis estão desempilhadas (uma separada da outra).
- Um banco de dados em formato *long* é aquele no qual as variáveis estão empilhadas (uma sobre a outra).

A figura a seguir exemplifica isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que, no formato *wide*, `x` e `y` são os nomes da variáveis. Quando você converte o banco de dados para o formato *long*, os valores destas variáveis serão empilhados com o respectivo nome da variável ao seu lado (isto é, em outra coluna), indicando que estes valores correspondem a ela.

> Quais pacotes/funções no R podem ser usados para transformar uma tabela wide em long e vice-e-versa?

No `r utils` você pode utilizar a função `stack` (empilhar) para converter um `data.frame` de *wide* para *long*:

```
dataset<-data.frame(matrix(runif(6*5,1,10),ncol=6)) # criação do data.frame
dataset

        X1       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6
1 7.349284 6.028351 2.688078 6.125223 1.221548 9.612955
2 4.069976 2.874686 6.672611 7.392773 8.788791 1.947049
3 5.601091 5.088117 6.642646 1.919682 5.083521 2.890271
4 8.972191 5.440744 1.900963 2.321034 4.617486 3.135706
5 6.863326 3.664501 8.406267 2.357013 7.787931 5.592315

empilhar<-stack(dataset,select=(1:6)) # converte para o formato long
empilhar
     values ind
1  7.349284  X1
2  4.069976  X1
3  5.601091  X1
4  8.972191  X1
5  6.863326  X1
6  6.028351  X2
7  2.874686  X2
8  5.088117  X2
9  5.440744  X2
10 3.664501  X2
11 2.688078  X3
12 6.672611  X3
13 6.642646  X3
14 1.900963  X3
15 8.406267  X3
16 6.125223  X4
17 7.392773  X4
18 1.919682  X4
19 2.321034  X4
20 2.357013  X4
21 1.221548  X5
22 8.788791  X5
23 5.083521  X5
24 4.617486  X5
25 7.787931  X5
26 9.612955  X6
27 1.947049  X6
28 2.890271  X6
29 3.135706  X6
30 5.592315  X6
```

A função `unstack` realiza o processo inverso. Isto é, converte de *long* para *wide*:

```
desempilhar<-unstack(empilhar) # converte para o formato wide

        X1       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6
1 7.349284 6.028351 2.688078 6.125223 1.221548 9.612955
2 4.069976 2.874686 6.672611 7.392773 8.788791 1.947049
3 5.601091 5.088117 6.642646 1.919682 5.083521 2.890271
4 8.972191 5.440744 1.900963 2.321034 4.617486 3.135706
5 6.863326 3.664501 8.406267 2.357013 7.787931 5.592315
```

No `tidyverse`, o *package* `tidyr` também é útil para fazer o que deseja.
Para empilhar, você pode utilizar a função `gather`. Considerando o mesmo conjunto de dados:

```
library(tidyr)

res1<-gather(dataset, key='factor', value = 'my', 1:6)
head(res1,10)

   factor       my
1      X1 5.938725
2      X1 4.367486
3      X1 3.220609
4      X1 3.357561
5      X1 9.275956
6      X2 2.260197
7      X2 5.880264
8      X2 2.891555
9      X2 7.641574
10     X2 9.611466
```

- onde: `key` é o nome do vetor que comportará os nomes das variáveis empilhadas;
  `value` representa as variáveis a serem empilhadas.

O processo inverso da função `gather` é dado pela função `spread` (semelhante a `unstack`). Mais detalhes na [documentação](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/tidyr.pdf).

Existem outros *packages* que fazem o mesmo (como `reshape2`).

**Principais utilidades dos dados em formato *long*:**

- **Cria grupos automaticamente para as variáveis** (útil em algumas análises, como ANOVA). Além disso, em algumas funções do `tidyverse`, como `ggplot::facet_wrap`, os dados precisam estar neste formato.
- **Evita a execução de loops**, ao usar a variável de grupo como se fossem colunas de um `data.frame`.