# Legenda no ggplot não aparece

Tags: r, ggplot2

Não sei o que estou fazendo errado, pois a legenda não aparece no gráfico que construo. Segue meu código:

```
ND<-c("D0","D1","D2","D3e4") #diferentes níveis de desfolha (D)
Vreal<-c(0.1985479,0.2060983,0.1611603,0.1214494) #volume real das árvores
Vest_g=c(0.1892300,0.1964590,0.1529276,0.1296224) #vol estimado sem considerar D
Vest_d=c(0.1970788,0.2039802,0.1607308,0.1186836) #vol estimado considerando D
EP_Vreal=c(0.007480623,0.009235496,0.010960471,0.008099734) #Erro padrão da média
EP_Vest_g=c(0.007224098,0.008119300,0.009906934,0.008238645)
EP_Vest_d=c(0.005887057,0.007898459,0.010907461,0.007151453)

Volume<-data.frame(ND,Vreal,Vest_g,Vest_d,EP_Vreal,EP_Vest_g,EP_Vest_d)

 # plot dataframe
ggplot(Volume, aes(x = ND)) +
  labs(x = "Níveis de desfolha",
       y = "Vol. ind. total com casca (m³)") +
       theme(legend.position="top")+
       scale_fill_discrete(name="Legenda",
                           labels=c("Vreal", "Vest_g", "Vest_d")) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(y = Vreal),
    stat = "identity",
    fill = "seagreen1",
    width = .2,
    position = position_nudge(x = -.20),
    ) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Vreal-EP_Vreal, ymax = Vreal+EP_Vreal), position = position_nudge(x = -.20), width = 0.1) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(y = Vest_g),
    stat = "identity",
    fill = "darkturquoise",
    width = .2,
    position = position_nudge(x = 0)
    ) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Vest_g-EP_Vest_g, ymax = Vest_g+EP_Vest_g), position = position_nudge(x = 0), width = 0.1) +
  geom_bar(
    aes(y = Vest_d),
    stat = "identity",
    fill = "cyan",
    width = .2,
    position = position_nudge(x = .20)
    ) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Vest_d-EP_Vest_d, ymax = Vest_d+EP_Vest_d), position = position_nudge(x = .20), width = 0.1)
```

Resultado: gráfico sem legenda

[image: Gráfico de saída]

Comment: O que você quer fazer? Só adicionar a legenda?

Comment: Olá, sim, quero adicionar a legenda. Tentei muitas coisas e não consegui.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O ggplot não está colocando as legendas automaticamente porque, da forma como estas fazer o gráfico, ele acha que não tem necessidade. Ao criar cada geometria você está especificando a cor como um atributo estético e não como uma variável que deve ser mapeada em uma estética (dentro do `aes()`).

A diferença entre mapear uma variável na cor e dar um valor para um atributo estético é que no segundo caso a imagem gerada não ganha nenhuma informação e, por isso mesmo, ela não precisa de uma legenda.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point(col = "cyan")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A coisa muda um pouco de figura quando uma variável é mapeada em alguma estética, digamos, uma cor. Neste caso a cor irá trazer uma informação e por este motivo deve poder ser decodificada com auxílio de uma legenda.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point(aes(col = factor(cyl)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O ggplot trabalha melhor com [tabelas longas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360773) do que largas. Neste caso o primeiro passo a fazer é criar uma tabela no formato longo.

```
library(tidyverse)

medidas <- Volume %>% 
  select(ND, starts_with("V")) %>% 
  gather(medida, valor, -ND)

desvios <- Volume %>% 
  select(ND, starts_with("EP")) %>% 
  gather(tipo, desvio, -ND) %>% 
  select(-ND)

tidy_vol <- bind_cols(medidas, desvios)
```

Como esse `data.frame` é possível até simplificar o código para criação do gráfico

```
ggplot(tidy_vol, aes(ND, valor, fill = medida)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = valor-desvio, ymax = valor+desvio), 
                position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.5)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para utilizar as cores que desejas, basta incluir as cores na escada de cores usadas pelo gráfico:

```
ggplot(tidy_vol, aes(ND, valor, fill = medida)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = valor-desvio, ymax = valor+desvio), 
                position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("seagreen1", "darkturquoise", "cyan"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tomás Barcelos, muito obrigada pela ajuda.