# Como consolidar conjunto de dados com dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Olá,

Tenho um conjunto de dados `sinan18` que contem informações sobre surtos alimentares no Brasil. Formatando a tabela original - que é enorme com o dplyr, cheguei no seguinte resultado:

```
> str(sinan18)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   13163 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ estado  : chr  "DF" "RS" "RS" "RS" ...
 $ regiao  : Factor w/ 5 levels "Centro-Oeste",..: 1 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ data    : chr  "05/05/2000" "22/05/2000" "22/05/2000" "22/05/2000" ...
 $ ano     : int  2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 ...
 $ agente1 : chr  "Ignorado" "Salmonella spp." "Salmonella spp." "Ignorado" ...
 $ agente2 : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ alimento: chr  "Alimentos mistos" "Ovos e produtos à base de ovos" "Ovos e produtos à base de ovos" "Ovos e produtos à base de ovos" ...
 $ local   : Factor w/ 13 levels "Asilo","Casos dispersos em mais de um município",..: 6 12 12 12 12 12 10 12 12 12 .

sinan18 %>%
  group_by(agente1)%>%
  count(regiao)

 1 " Cryptosporidium"      Sudeste     12
 2 Adenovírus              Nordeste     2
 3 Adenovírus              Sudeste      2
 4 Aeromonas               Nordeste     2
 5 Aeromonas               Sudeste      5
 6 Aeromonas               Sul          2
 7 "Aeromonas hidrophila " Nordeste     1
 8 "Aeromonas hidrophila " Sudeste      1
 9 Aeromonas spp.          Nordeste     3
 10 Amebíase                Sul          1
```

Entretanto, eu necessito consolidar uma tabela onde as regiões sejam as variáveis (colunas) e os microrganismos as observações (linhas). Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Olá, use o comando `dput(sinan18)` para fazer uma amostra de seus dados, e edite seu tópico, assim ficará mais fácil entender a sua dúvida e testar no seus dados.

Comment: Está à procura [disto (SO em Inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)?

Answer (score 1):

Para transformar os valores em colunas, é possível usar a função `spread()` do pacote [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr). Ver mais sobre essas transformações [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360773/43953).

```r
sinan_count <- tibble::tribble(
                ~agente1,    ~regiao,  ~n,
       "Cryptosporidium",  "Sudeste", 12L,
            "Adenovírus", "Nordeste",  2L,
            "Adenovírus",  "Sudeste",  2L,
             "Aeromonas", "Nordeste",  2L,
             "Aeromonas",  "Sudeste",  5L,
             "Aeromonas",      "Sul",  2L,
  "Aeromonas hidrophila", "Nordeste",  1L,
  "Aeromonas hidrophila",  "Sudeste",  1L,
        "Aeromonas spp.", "Nordeste",  3L,
              "Amebíase",      "Sul",  1L
  )

tidyr::spread(sinan_count, regiao, n)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   agente1              Nordeste Sudeste   Sul
#>   <chr>                   <int>   <int> <int>
#> 1 Adenovírus                  2       2    NA
#> 2 Aeromonas                   2       5     2
#> 3 Aeromonas hidrophila        1       1    NA
#> 4 Aeromonas spp.              3      NA    NA
#> 5 Amebíase                   NA      NA     1
#> 6 Cryptosporidium            NA      12    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Caso a ausência de informações nessa contagem represente um valor distinto de NA (valores ausentes), por exemplo zero casos, é possível informá-lo com o argumento `fill`.

```
tidyr::spread(sinan_count, regiao, n, fill = c(n = 0L))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   agente1              Nordeste Sudeste   Sul
#>   <chr>                   <int>   <int> <int>
#> 1 Adenovírus                  2       2     0
#> 2 Aeromonas                   2       5     2
#> 3 Aeromonas hidrophila        1       1     0
#> 4 Aeromonas spp.              3       0     0
#> 5 Amebíase                    0       0     1
#> 6 Cryptosporidium             0      12     0
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente aqui! Muito obrigado!