# Criar um gráfico de barras no ggplot2 com colunas justapostas

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gostaria de criar um gráfico de barras no `ggplot2` com `x1` e `x2` lado a lado comparando mês a mês. Tentei o seguinte código, mas não obtive sucesso:

```
Mean_2013 <- read.table("https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/master/Mean_2013.txt",header = TRUE)
str(Mean_2013)
ggplot(Mean_2013) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=(reorder(Mes,Mes_id)),y=x1, fill=x2), stat = "identity", position='dodge')
```

Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, o segredo é o que Marcus falou, transformar para o formato tidy.
Sugiro as seguintes bibliografias a respeito:

- [R for data science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz);
- [Tidy Data](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

Vou deixar também uma maneira adicional de se fazer a transformação para o formato tidy, usando apenas o pacote `tidyr` da biblioteca `tidyverse` (mesma biblioteca do `ggplot`).

```
library(tidyverse)
link = "https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/master/Mean_2013.txt"
Mean_2013 <- read.table(link, header = TRUE)

#transformar os dados para o formato tidy
Mean_2013 %>% gather(variavel, valor, -Mes, -Mes_id) -> mean2013_tidy

#plotando o gráfico
mean2013_tidy %>%
  ggplot(aes(x =reorder(Mes, Mes_id),y = valor, fill = variavel)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  labs(x = "Mês", y = "Valor")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 4):

O segredo é colocar os dados em [formato longo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360773/o-que-s%C3%A3o-dados-no-formato-wide-long). Uma maneira de fazer isto é utilizando o pacote `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

Mean_2013 <- read.table("https://raw.githack.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/master/Mean_2013.txt", header = TRUE)
Mean_2013_melt <- melt(Mean_2013, id = c("Mes", "Mes_id"))

ggplot(Mean_2013_melt) + 
  geom_col(aes(x=(reorder(Mes, Mes_id)), y=value, fill=variable), position='dodge')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]