# Como colocar legendas em um gráfico de linhas no ggplo2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

Tenho um gráfico de linhas com duas variáveis e necessito colocar a legenda de cada uma, porém, não estou conseguindo.

Estou usando um código como esse:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- c(1:50)
dado <- c(1:50)
dado1 <- c(1:25)

dados <- data.frame(Data = data, "1" = dado, "2" = dado1)

ggplot(data = dados) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Data, y = X1), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(x = Data, y = X2), color = "red") +
  labs(x = "Dado", y = "Dado2", color = "Casos") +
  ggtitle("Teste")
```

Como consigo definir a legenda de cada uma das variáveis? Com o `labs`, ele só plota a legenda dos eixos X e Y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A melhor maneira de plotar dados da maneira que tu deseja é colocá-los no formato longo. [Leia essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360773/o-que-s%C3%A3o-dados-no-formato-wide-long) aqui mesmo no StackOverflow para saber o que é isso. Em resumo, é necessário criar uma coluna no teu conjunto de dados que identifique os diferentes casos X1 e X2. A função `melt` do pacote `reshape2` faz isso automaticamente:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

data <- c(1:50)
dado <- c(1:50)
dado1 <- c(1:25)

dados <- data.frame(Data = data, "1" = dado, "2" = dado1)

dados <- melt(dados, id.vars = "Data")

head(dados)
#>   Data variable value
#> 1    1       X1     1
#> 2    2       X1     2
#> 3    3       X1     3
#> 4    4       X1     4
#> 5    5       X1     5
#> 6    6       X1     6
```

Não é necessário renomear as colunas. Seria possível manter `Data`, `variable` e `value`. Eu mudei os nomes para fins didáticos.

```r
names(dados) <- c("Data", "Casos", "Valor")

head(dados)
#>   Data Casos Valor
#> 1    1    X1     1
#> 2    2    X1     2
#> 3    3    X1     3
#> 4    4    X1     4
#> 5    5    X1     5
#> 6    6    X1     6

ggplot(data = dados, aes(x = Data, y = Valor, color = Casos)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = "Dado", y = "Dado2", color = "Casos") +
    ggtitle("Teste")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Algumas das grandes vantagens de utilizar os dados em formato longo são

- utilizar as funções do pacote `dplyr` caso queira realizar agrupamentos de dados a partir da coluna `Casos`
- digitar menos código; imagine se houvessem 10 linhas a serem plotadas e fosse preciso digitar `geom_line` 10 vezes?
- a legenda é construída automaticamente
- alterar facilmente a paleta de cores do gráfico criado

```r
ggplot(data = dados, aes(x = Data, y = Valor, color = Casos)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = "Dado", y = "Dado2", color = "Casos") +
    ggtitle("Teste") +
    scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>