# Como transformar uma tabela com colunas com dias e linhas com meses para uma série temporal regular?

Tags: r, tabela-html, series-temporais

Eu tenho uma tabela de dados em excel que foi organizado de forma estranha. As colunas são meses e linhas são dias. No arquivo, após 31 dias, recomeça a conta do dia. Neste caso, começa outro ano. Eu queria saber como posso transformar esses dados numa série temporal regular. Sabendo que a série começa em 1980, tem como organizar?

Desde já agradeço.

dados

```
read.table(text = "DIA;JAN;FEV;MAR;ABR;MAI;JUN;JUL;AGO;SET;OUT;NOV;DEZ
1;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
2;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
3;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;4.4;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
4;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
5;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;1.9;.0;.0;.0;.0  
6;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;3.4;15.4;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
7;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
8;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
9;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
10;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
11;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
12;NA;NA;.0;1.9;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
13;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
14;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
15;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;7.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
16;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;2.2;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
17;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
18;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;1.3;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
19;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
20;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
21;NA;NA;.0;.0;2.5;.0;1.7;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
22;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
23;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;6.8;.0;.0;.0;.0;17.7;.0   
24;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;2.4;.0;3.1;.0;.0;.0;.0    
25;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;2.1;.0;4.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
26;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;2.6;.0;.0;.0;.0 
27;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
28;NA;NA;.0;.0;1.8;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
29;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
30;NA;NA;12.5;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
31;NA;NA;.0;NA;.0;NA;.0;.0;NA;.0;NA;.0  
1;25.8;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;7.2;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
2;6.5;17.2;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
3;.0;.0;60.0;3.5;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;3.5;.0
4;1.8;.0;10.1;.0;.0;11.5;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
5;.0;.0;10.6;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
6;.0;.0;21.7;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
7;.0;.0;28.8;3.4;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
8;.0;6.8;59.8;.0;4.6;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
9;.0;.0;13.6;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
10;.0;.0;19.1;.0;.0;.0;.0;6.5;.0;.0;.0;.0", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro vamos criar um objeto `dados` com os dados brutos da tabela.

```r
dados <- read.table(text = "DIA;JAN;FEV;MAR;ABR;MAI;JUN;JUL;AGO;SET;OUT;NOV;DEZ
1;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
2;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
3;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;4.4;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
4;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
5;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;1.9;.0;.0;.0;.0  
6;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;3.4;15.4;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
7;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
8;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
9;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
10;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
11;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
12;NA;NA;.0;1.9;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
13;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
14;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
15;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;7.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
16;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;2.2;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
17;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
18;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;1.3;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
19;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
20;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
21;NA;NA;.0;.0;2.5;.0;1.7;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
22;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
23;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;6.8;.0;.0;.0;.0;17.7;.0   
24;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;2.4;.0;3.1;.0;.0;.0;.0    
25;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;2.1;.0;4.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
26;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;2.6;.0;.0;.0;.0 
27;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
28;NA;NA;.0;.0;1.8;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
29;NA;NA;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
30;NA;NA;12.5;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
31;NA;NA;.0;NA;.0;NA;.0;.0;NA;.0;NA;.0  
1;25.8;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;7.2;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
2;6.5;17.2;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
3;.0;.0;60.0;3.5;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;3.5;.0
4;1.8;.0;10.1;.0;.0;11.5;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0  
5;.0;.0;10.6;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
6;.0;.0;21.7;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
7;.0;.0;28.8;3.4;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0    
8;.0;6.8;59.8;.0;4.6;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0   
9;.0;.0;13.6;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0;.0 
10;.0;.0;19.1;.0;.0;.0;.0;6.5;.0;.0;.0;.0", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

E então podemos proceder a manipulação dos dados para alcançar o objetivo desejado.

```r
library(tidyverse)
dados_organizados <- dados %>% 
  gather(mes, valor, -DIA) %>% 
  group_by(DIA, mes) %>% 
  mutate(ano = seq_along(valor))
```

A solução passou por duas etapas:

1. Mudar o formato da tabela de *wide* para *long* (ver mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360773/));
2. Criar uma variável com o ano

A parte 1 não tem muito o que explicar porque é uma transformação padrão. A documentação da função e a pergunta vinculada acima devem ajudar caso precise de maiores informações sobre esse passo.

Já a parte 2, um criei uma variável nova que conta a quantidade de vezes que um conjunto de dia e mês aparecem, servindo assim como o ano.

O código abaixo pode ser usada para ver as informações do ano 2, que batem com as informações da tabela original.

```r
dados_organizados %>% 
  filter(ano == 2)
#> # A tibble: 120 x 4
#> # Groups:   DIA, mes [120]
#>      DIA mes   valor   ano
#>    <int> <chr> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     1 JAN    25.8     2
#>  2     2 JAN     6.5     2
#>  3     3 JAN     0       2
#>  4     4 JAN     1.8     2
#>  5     5 JAN     0       2
#>  6     6 JAN     0       2
#>  7     7 JAN     0       2
#>  8     8 JAN     0       2
#>  9     9 JAN     0       2
#> 10    10 JAN     0       2
#> # … with 110 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>