# Como especificar as colunas do facet_grid no ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

Estou utilizando os dados de mobilidade do Google para montar alguns gráficos, necessitava fazer um gráfico 5x5, onde nas linhas seriam os estados e nas colunas, os locais. Tentei utilizar o `facet_grid`, mas não deu certo.

Gostaria que a estrutura do gráfico ficasse da seguinte forma, com os "-" sinalizando os gráficos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ao utilizar o `facet_grid`, o gráfico está saindo dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código que estou utilizando:

```
library(tidyverse)

google <- read_csv("https://www.gstatic.com/covid19/mobility/Global_Mobility_Report.csv") %>%
  filter(country_region == "Brazil") %>%
  select(-c(country_region_code, country_region, sub_region_2, iso_3166_2_code, census_fips_code)) %>%
  mutate(sub_region_1 = ifelse(is.na(sub_region_1), "Brazil", sub_region_1),
         sub_region_1 = gsub(sub_region_1, pattern = "State of ", replacement = ""))

colnames(google) <- gsub(pattern = "_percent_change_from_baseline",
                                   replacement = "",
                                   x = colnames(google))

estados <- c("São Paulo", "Minas Gerais", "Rio de Janeiro", "Rio Grande do Sul",
             "Paraná")

google %>%
  filter(sub_region_1 %in% estados) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = transit_stations)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = parks)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = grocery_and_pharmacy)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = retail_and_recreation)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = workplaces)) +
  facet_grid(sub_region_1 ~ .)
```

Como faço para deixar o gráfico da forma mostrada acima? Com as variáveis sendo as colunas e os estados as linhas?

Comment: Você chegou quase lá. Faltou deixar os dados tidy e usar isso no facet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para usar os facets da forma pretendida, os dados tem que ser transformados para um formato *tidy* (ver mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360773/o-que-s%c3%a3o-dados-no-formato-wide-long)) em que as métricas são colocadas numa variável e suas medidas em outra. O código abaixo faz isso:

```
tidy_google <- google %>%
  filter(sub_region_1 %in% estados) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(sub_region_1, date), 
               names_to = "variavel", 
               values_to = "valor")
head(tidy_google)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  sub_region_1 date       variavel              valor
  <chr>        <date>     <chr>                 <dbl>
1 Minas Gerais 2020-02-15 retail_and_recreation     7
2 Minas Gerais 2020-02-15 grocery_and_pharmacy      5
3 Minas Gerais 2020-02-15 parks                    11
4 Minas Gerais 2020-02-15 transit_stations         10
5 Minas Gerais 2020-02-15 workplaces                8
6 Minas Gerais 2020-02-15 residential               0
```

Como se pode ver, criamos um novo `data.frame` em que as variáveis são rearanjadas da forma acima. A variável com o nome das métricas foi chamada de `variavel` e as suas medidas ficaram na coluna chamada `valor`.

Com isso, basta adicionar a `variavel` no `facet_wrap` e temos o resultado desejado.

```
ggplot(tidy_google, aes(x = date, valor)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(sub_region_1 ~ variavel)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado! Aproveitando a pergunta, existe alguma maneira de agregar o dado e uma linha com a média móvel de 7 dias desse mesmo dado?

Comment: Você pode agrupar for variável e fazer a média movel usando o `tidy_google`