# Gráfico de Composição usando ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como posso produzir um gráfico de composição usando ggplot2 reproduzindo o mesmo modelo da figura abaixo?

[image: Exemplo do gráfico a ser produzido]

Matrix de exemplo:

```
x<-c(0, 1.52, 8.12, 0, 0.29, 0, 3, 4, 1.2, 1.1)
y<-c(4.8, 3.03, 6.82, 9.76, 0.59, 0.5, 5, 1.6, 0, 0)
z<-c(4, 13.63, 22.73, 0, 12.2, 24, 47, 9.6, 10.84, 14.29)

comp<-cbind(x, y, z)
row.names(comp)<-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primeira providência a se tomar é colocar os dados no [formato longo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360773/o-que-s%C3%A3o-dados-no-formato-wide-long). Felizmente, o pacote `reshape2` facilita muito esse trabalho:

```r
x<-c(0, 1.52, 8.12, 0, 0.29, 0, 3, 4, 1.2, 1.1)
y<-c(4.8, 3.03, 6.82, 9.76, 0.59, 0.5, 5, 1.6, 0, 0)
z<-c(4, 13.63, 22.73, 0, 12.2, 24, 47, 9.6, 10.84, 14.29)

comp<-cbind(x, y, z)
row.names(comp)<-c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")

library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'reshape2'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     smiths

comp.long <- melt(comp)

head(comp.long)
#>   Var1 Var2 value
#> 1    a    x  0.00
#> 2    b    x  1.52
#> 3    c    x  8.12
#> 4    d    x  0.00
#> 5    e    x  0.29
#> 6    f    x  0.00
```

Com os dados formatados corretamente, basta plotá-los como se fossem um gráfico de dispersão. `Var1` é considerado o eixo x, por exemplo, e `Var2` pode ser o eixo y. A seguir, basta adicionar o mapeamento das cores e do tamanho dos pontos à coluna `value`. Depois removi a legenda referente ao tamanho dos pontos, pois ela é redundante se já tivermos essa informação presente na cor. Para finalizar, criei uma escala de cores em um gradiente, saindo do azul e indo para o vermelho, como na figura usada no exemplo.

```r
ggplot(comp.long, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2, colour = value)) +
    geom_point(aes(size = value)) +
    guides(size = FALSE) +
    scale_colour_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>